# How to change extrude direction for bezier?

Tags: bezier-curves, extrude

I have a model ready which I draw at first in 2D. But when I tried to extrude the line, it extrudes that in flat and not up. What is the mistake I have made and can it be fixed still?

Here I have example which shows how it is working at the moment and which I would like to see happening.

[image]

Or would it be easier to just re-draw it?

Comment: If you want to extrude up, you can just use E and the Z to lock axis (or X, Y)

Comment: Thanks @Vagabonk, but that is still bezier curve which I would like to extrude. Of course I could convert that to mesh, but I would like to understand why it works like that and how to fix it, and perhaps preventing that in future.

Comment: Sorry, then. Could you please explain the process a little more? How did the top mesh come into being?

Comment: @Vagabonk sorry to say, but I'm not actually sure how I originally end to that issue. But I believe it could be because of rotate at the begin. So if you create new bezier curve, rotate it in 90 degrees on x-axle, and then start drawing from top perspective (on XY coordinator).

Except above simple option I was able to get fixed with tilt (alt - t). Looks like I need to practicing more what the tilt means in practical level.

Comment: While you are in Edit Mode you can go to Overlays, in the top right, and turn on Normals (the last check box). Maybe that will help you understand a little bit more?

Comment: Maybe you've rotated it and you need to apply the rotation? If you want to keep it rotated for some reason, tilt the vertices in Edit mode (Ctrl T 90)

Comment: I could not found the way to fix it. So I redraw it.

Thank you for your help.